# GeoLocation with FourSquare and Google Maps

Tags: objective-c, geolocation, foursquare, location-based-service

How can i place Foursquare venues on a Google Map in objective C . I found source code in php and c/java but how can i embedded this module in my code . Does exist any way to make it in objective c for ios app ?

http://www.ppi.io/blog/1/tutorial-geolocation-with-foursquare-and-google-maps

Answer (score 1):

First of all it is recommended for you to use one of the [SDKs](https://developer.foursquare.com/resources/libraries). After you successfully added a FourSquare iOS SDK to your project, you can send some queries to get some venues. For example, you can call [userGetVenueHistory](https://github.com/Constantine-Fry/Foursquare-API-v2/blob/master/Foursquare2/Foursquare2.h#L311) method to get history of user's. Of course you need user to login with your application first for this case. However, after you get some venues you will have coordinates of the venues.

Then you need to add [Google Maps iOS SDK](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/) to your project. After all as it is exposed in the Google Maps iOS SDK page, you can create some markers as follows:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(41.887, -87.622);
marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"flag_icon"];
//I assume you created the map.
marker.map = mapView;
```

I strongly recommend you to have a look on the example projects on [Github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=foursquare&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93), [Github](https://github.com/search?l=Objective-C&q=google%20maps&ref=searchresults&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Good Luck.